# Query not complete - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

My query so far:

```
SELECT CD_no, purchasedate, COUNT(*) mostsales
FROM Sales A
GROUP BY CD_no, purchasedate
HAVING COUNT(*) =
        (SELECT MAX(mostsales)
         FROM
            (SELECT CD_no, purchasedate, COUNT(*) AS mostsales
                FROM Sales
            GROUP BY CD_no, purchasedate) B
            WHERE CD_no = A.CD_no)
```

My query so far generates from an input of CD_no's and purchase's, finds date had the most sales for that specific CD. However this only returns one value for each CD number. However there may be a possibility that a CD_no may have the exact same maximal purchases on two different dates, and therefore should display both dates against the CD number.

Current output:

```
CD_NO           mostsales
1             2011-12-30
2             2012-03-22
3             2012-04-24
```

Desired output:

```
CD_NO           mostsales
1             2011-12-30
2             2012-03-22
3             2012-04-24
3             2012-04-22
```

From the following input:

```
CD_NO         purchase_date
1              2011-12-30
1              2011-12-30
1              2011-12-29
1              2011-12-28
2              2012-03-22
2              2012-03-22
2              2012-03-21
3              2012-04-24
3              2012-04-24
3              2012-04-22
3              2012-04-22              
3              2012-04-21
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. The desired output shows CD_NO 1 only for 2011-12-30, but CD_NO 1 was also the top seller for 2011-12-29 and 2011-12-28. What do you mean by "the most sales"?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Sounds like you need to add an aggregate function:</strike>

```
SELECT CD_NO, purchase_date, Count(purchase_date) totalSales
FROM Artist
GROUP BY purchase_date
ORDER BY CD_NO
```

MySQL allows you to limit the number of fields that you `GROUP BY` so this above is only grouping on the `purchase_date`.

In other RDBMS, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT a1.CD_NO, a1.purchase_date, a2.TotalSalesByDate
FROM Artist a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(purchase_date) TotalSalesByDate, purchase_date
    FROM Artist
    GROUP BY purchase_date
) a2
   on a1.purchase_date= a2.purchase_date
ORDER BY a1.CD_NO
```

Edit: Based on your updates, you should be able to use something similar to this:

```
SELECT a1.CD_NO, date_format(a1.purchase_date, '%Y-%m-%d') MostSales
FROM Artist a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(purchase_date) TotalSalesByDate, purchase_date
    FROM Artist
    GROUP BY purchase_date
) a2
   on a1.purchase_date= a2.purchase_date
group by a1.CD_NO, a1.purchase_date
having max(TotalSalesByDate) = (select max(Total) totalsales
                                 from
                                 (
                                    SELECT cd_no, purchase_date, Count(purchase_date) Total
                                    FROM Artist a1
                                    GROUP BY cd_no, purchase_date
                                 ) src
                                 where a1.cd_no = src.cd_no
                                 GROUP BY cd_no);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f46d/59)

Result:

```
| CD_NO |  MOSTSALES |
----------------------
|     1 | 2011-12-30 |
|     2 | 2012-03-22 |
|     3 | 2012-04-22 |
|     3 | 2012-04-24 |
```

Comment: This list's just how many were brought on that specific day, where I don't need to the counts, just the dates, but needs to be ordered by the counts if you know what i mean.

Comment: @user1854392 can you edit your post with the table structure, some sample data and then the desired result of the query?

Comment: +1 Very glad you pointed out that MySQL's `GROUP BY` is crap.

Comment: I have edited publication_date to purchase_dates, as these are all different dates (sorry typo), and from this purchase dates to find which date had the most sales for each CD and list them. And yes will re-edit post with desired output

Comment: Hey thanks for your re-edit. The result table i have shows still all cd_no's against their purchase date.

Comment: @user1854392 based on the sample data you have provided, my last query is returning the desired result.  Does it not work in your database?  If not please explain what issues you are having.