# Nest Query - MYSQL - Find which dates had most sales on

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I'm having to write query where I need to list which CD's had the most sales on specific dates . Do to this I only have information about of all CD's and their Purchase dates. My query only lists the CD_NO's and all dates which they were brought on. I need to result table to give me which days had the MOST sales on, and order them by busiest date against the specific CD. I gather i need to make a subquery, but these confuse the heck out of me.

My query so far:

```
SELECT CD_NO, purchase_date
FROM Artist
GROUP BY CD_NO, purchase_date
ORDER BY CD_NO
```

Any Suggestions as i'm a little confused :(

The exact specification of query is:

For each CD, find out which days had the most sales. Result table needs to list the CD number, and the date of the day. Note that a CD can appear several times in the result table if there were several days that had an equal amount of maximum sales.

Desired output:

```
CD_NO        purchase_date
1             2011-12-30 
2             2012-03-22
3             2012-04-24
3             2012-04-22
```

Where CD_NO 1 had the most sales on specific date 2011-12-30, CD_NO 2 has the most sales of the date 2012-03-22 compared to all other purchase dates for CD_NO 2, and CD_NO 3 had joint number of most sales on both dates, so both dates are listed. This result table is derived from following input:

```
CD_NO         purchase_date
1              2011-12-30
1              2011-12-30
1              2011-12-29
1              2011-12-28
2              2012-03-22
2              2012-03-22
2              2012-03-21
3              2012-04-24
3              2012-04-24
3              2012-04-22
3              2012-04-22              
3              2012-04-21
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but the input isn't necessarily ordered by CD_NO, and the earliest date for the purchase date isn't always last. IE, the ordering of the input can be random but the output should be ordered by the CD_NO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query not complete - MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608817/query-not-complete-mysql)

Comment: Instead of reposting your question, you should edit the original question with additional details or to clarify the problem.